# My UIDatePicker Is Not Coming Propper format

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-datepicker

here is my code.

```
extension ProfileViewController {
    private func openDatePicker() {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        ageTextFieldOutlet.inputView = datePicker
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44))
        let cancleButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancle", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancleButtonClicked))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))
        let flexibleBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.setItems([cancleButton, flexibleBtn, doneButton], animated: true)
        ageTextFieldOutlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    
    @objc func cancleButtonClicked() {
        ageTextFieldOutlet.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    @objc func doneButtonClicked() {
        if let datePiker = ageTextFieldOutlet.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
            print(datePiker.date)
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate For Age
extension ProfileViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.openDatePicker()
    }
}
```

And Image For Better Understanding.

I Get this type of selector when I run my project
[image: I Get this type of selector when I run my project]

and I want this type of date selector
[image: and I want this type of date selector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer versions of iOS (13.4+) you need to specify a style if you want the wheel date picker, by default it is automatic, and it usually defaults to compact, in this case when you create a new UIDatePicker you can do this:

```swift
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        ageTextFieldOutlet.inputView = datePicker
```

#### Docs:

- [UIDatePicker - Change the Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker#2281468)
- [UIDatePicker - Styles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle)